# multiple route using same component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hello  Every one I have an issue with react router with routing i have two different files users and ads I create route of both `/ads/addetail` or `/users/userdetail` these routes is working fine but I have issue in user detail page when I click on userdetail it show me detail and I also fetch ads of this user and it also working fine there is a button in each ad which pushes me to addetail page but when I click it shows me empty screen no sidebar no navbar no data empty white screen but when I open it in ads/addetail page it working fine please help me, I don't understand what happened.
This is the route in userdetail page for addetail page thank you in advance

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/user-listing/${this.data.id}/ad-listing/${ad.id}`,
    state: { ad: ad }
  }}
>
  Detail
</Link>
```

Comment: Is there an error in your browser console? If so, please attach it to this question

Comment: I suppose `data` is in your component state so you may replace `this.data.id` by `this.state.data.id`

Comment: there is no error in browser and `this.data` fetch correct id issue is in addetail component it is not render from userdetal page

Comment: i found the error thank you jank for your help